# SQL Rolling Summary Statistics For Set Timeframe

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table that contains information about log-in events. Every time a user logs in, a record is added containing the user and the date. I want to calculate a new column in that table that holds the number of times that user has logged in in the past 31 days (including the current attempt). This is a simplified version of what my table looks like, including the column I want to add:

```
  UserID   Date          LoginsInPast31Days
 -------- ------------- --------------------
  1        01-01-2012     1
  2        02-01-2012     1
  2        10-01-2012     2
  1        25-01-2012     2
  2        03-02-2012     2
  2        22-03-2012     1
```

I know how to calculate a total amount of login attempts: I'd use `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY Date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)`. However, I want to limit the timeframe to the last 31 days. My guess is that I have to change the `UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`, but how do I alter it in such a way that it select the right amount of rows?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2012, but we will be upgrading to 2016 soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One pretty efficient way is to add a record 30 days after each date.  It looks like this:

```
select userid, dte,
       sum(inc) over (partition by userid order by dte) as LoginsInPast31Days
from ((select distinct userid, logindate as dte, 1 as inc from logins) union all
      (select distinct userid, dateadd(day, 31, dte, -1 as inc from logins)
     ) l;
```

Comment: This is genius! Thanks so much.

Comment: Just checking: I do still need the `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`, right? It's not in your answer, but I think it should be.

Comment: @A.Stam . . . It is implicit when you use `order by`.  There are some databases where the clause is needed (I think in Redshift), but not in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, 2 adjustments:

- First make sure to group by user and date so you know how many rows to select
- Secondly, you'll need to use 'ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 31 FOLLOWING' since you cannot limit the number of preceding records to use. By using descending sort order, you'll get the required result.

Combine these tips and you'll get:

```
SELECT SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (
          PARTITION BY t.userid_KEY 
          ORDER BY CAST(t.login_ts AS DATE) DESC 
          ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 31 FOLLOWING
       )
FROM table AS t
GROUP BY t.userid, CAST(t.login_ts AS DATE)
```